# How to do get Blog DB without password data in jparepository?

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I am studying Spring. I have a question. I want to make Controller. this is, bellow [BlogController] using [repository.findall()] method just get to Blog DB **without password**.

Please as let me understand, give me solution.

Thank you. ( I first time write that in English. I'm so curious. but, my googling so bad )

Blog domain

```
@Getter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Blog extends Timestamped{

@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long Id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String title;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String author;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String content;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int password;

public Blog(BlogRequestDto requestDto){
        this.title = requestDto.getTitle();
        this.author = requestDto.getAuthor();
        this.content = requestDto.getContent();
        this.password = requestDto.getPassword();
    }
}
```

BlogRepository

```
public interface BlogRepository extends JpaRepository<Blog, Long> {
    List<Blog> findAllByOrderByModifiedAtDesc();
}
```

BlogService

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Service
public class BlogService {

    private final BlogRepository repository;



    @Transactional
    public Long update(Long id, BlogRequestDto requestDto){
        Blog blog = repository.findById(id).orElseThrow(
                () -> new NullPointerException("no exist")
        );
     blog.update(requestDto);
     return blog.getId();
    }
}
```

BlogController

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RestController

public class BlogController {

    private final BlogRepository repository;
    private final BlogService blogService;

 
    @PostMapping("/api/post")
    public Blog createBlog(@RequestBody BlogRequestDto requestDto){
        Blog blog = new Blog(requestDto);
        return repository.save(blog);
    }


    !!!!! Help me !!!!
    @GetMapping("/api/post")
    public List<Blog> getAllBlog(){
        return repository.findAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: Without password for what? Database?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JPA Native Query. Cannot select specific columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69265720/jpa-native-query-cannot-select-specific-columns)